# How to use an injected service in a template?

Tags: angular

### Component

```
templateUrl : 'home.html'
..
providers:      [NavService]
..    
private navService:     NavService,
..
```

### Template

```
 <li *ngFor="let state of states; let i=index" 
[class.active]="navService.isCurrentState(state)">

<span class="name">{{navService[state].name}}</span>
```

does not seem to work, what am I missing here? How can I access my service in my component template?

Comment: For this you need to show us how do you use isCurrentState function in service?

Answer (score 21):

Every property defined within the component class can be used in the template.

First, you could check that you have the correct value for `navService`:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [NavService]
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(public navService: NavService) {
    console.log(navService); // <----
  }
}
```

Comment: Question for bonus points - should service public properties be called directly from templates? Or is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: I REALLY would like to know this as well.

Comment: For @pootzko: This approach of injecting a public service and accessing it within the template appears to be OK (and not an anti-pattern) as it is demonstrated as a technique in the official Angular docs (Tour of Heroes tutorial): https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you declared the service as private.
According to the documentation ( [angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) ): "the messageService property must be public because you're going to bind to it in the template".
If you change it to public in costructor you can use the service inside the template.